# Coupled Differential Equations: GATE2020 Exam

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is question 33 from the [GATE 2020](http://gate.iitd.ac.in/gate2020/MAPaper.php) (Graduate Aptitude Test in Engineering) for Mathematics

> Let $u$ be a solution of the differential equation $y’+xy=0$ and $\phi=u\psi$ be a solution of the differential equation $y’’+2xy’+(x^2+2)y=0$ such that  $\phi(0)=1,\phi’(0)=0$. Then $\phi(x)$ is equal to
>
> (A) $(\cos^2(x))e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$
> (B) $(\cos(x))e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$
> (C) $(1+x^2)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$
> (D) $(\cos(x))e^{-x^2}$

$u$ is obtained as $u(x)=ce^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$, but I don’t know how to solve the second differential equation. If I put $u\psi$ in this equation, it is not a simple expression.

$$ (u’’\psi+u\psi’’+2u’\psi’ )+2x(u\psi’+u’\psi’) +(x^2+2)u\psi=  (u’’\psi+u\psi’’ )+2x(u’\psi’) +(x^2+2)u\psi $$

Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Some missing context : What is GATE-2020 ? A departure booth in a very big airport ?

Comment: @JeanMarie ok sir I will edit it

Comment: @JeanMarie sir that was nothing but an exam name .

Comment: Notice you can differentiate the first equation to get a second order differential equations. These two equations can be used to simplify the overall second equation. You can use the solution to the first from there to cleanup and solve.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost tempting to use [reduction of order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order) here but unfortunately that doesn't work here as $u$ is not a solution of $\color{blue}{y''+2xy'+(x^2+2)y=0}$. So now the natural way is to use the given fact that $\phi$ is a solution of the blue colored ODE while noting that the blue colored ODE is a homogeneous one so there is some 'hope' of cancellation of some terms. You are almost there.

---

Consider $u=e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$ (just taking $c=1$ in $u$ that you obtained and this can be done due to homogeneity of the blue colored ODE). Then note that $u'=-xe^{-\frac{x^2}2}$ and $ u''=(x^2-1)e^{-\frac {x^2}{2}}$. Substitute $\phi=u\psi$ in $y''+2xy'+(x^2+2)y=0$ to get
\begin{align*}
&(u’’\psi+u\psi’’+2u’\psi’ )+2x(u\psi’+u’\psi’) +(x^2+2)u\psi=  e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} (\psi''+\psi)\\
&\text{It follows that } e^{-\frac{x^2}2}(\psi''+\psi)=0\\
&\text{which gives } \psi''+\psi=0\implies \psi(x)=a\cos x+b\sin x ,\text{ where $a$ and $b$ are unknown coefficients.}\\
&\text{Using the initial value conditions, it follows that } a=1, b=0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully the Gate aspirants,this problem  can be solved in two parts.

Part $1$  is to find the solution of your first ODE. You have successfully find that.Part $2$ is you just put the value of $ u(x)$ in $ phi(x) $.Then your $phi(x)$ function is ready to be differentiated.Now  you have some  knowledge about $phi(x)$ that it is a solution of the  given second ode.

Differentiate it and put into the second and you will get a second order ode with reduced coefficients. Solve it and you get finally $ phi(x) $.

Check that your answer should be option (b).

Comment: Your question says that your  solution will consist some part of "u"

Comment: Look with open eyes that phi(x)= u(x)sy(x) is given as a solution  of second ode. Differentiate phi(x) and put it in the ode.

Comment: No reduction is done ! only  satisfaction is done to the problem with given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\phi=u\psi$. Then since $u'=-xu$ we also get $u'' = -u-xu'=-u+x^2u$. Thus
$\phi' = (-xu)\psi + u\psi'=u(\psi'-x\psi)$ and $\phi'' = u(x^2-1)\psi + (-xu)\psi' + (-xu)\psi' + u\psi'' = u((x^2-1)\psi-2x\psi' + \psi'')$.

Thus
$$ 0=u((x^2-1)\psi-2x\psi' + \psi'') + 2xu(\psi'-x\psi) + (x^2+2)u\psi =
u( \psi(x^2-1-2x^2+x^2+2) + \psi'(-2x+2x) + \psi'') = u( \psi+\psi'')$$

Now if $u$ is not the trivial solution $u\equiv 0$ we can thus divide be $u$ to get
$$ \psi'' + \psi = 0$$
the solution of which is of the form $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$. Now it suffices to see that a non trivial solution to $y'=-xy$ cannot be periodic (if $x<0$ the sign of $y'$ is equal to the sign of $y$).

Thus the only options are B,D. This means $\psi(x)=\cos(x)$,and thus either $u=e^{-x^2/2}$ or $e^{-x^2}$. By differentiating this we can see that only B satisfies the condition $u'=-xu$.